# Has the 1-party rule of PRC helped them to keep the most historical China in one piece?

Tags: china, geopolitics, chinese-communist-party

My argument is if PRC were a democracy, foreign interference would have been much bigger (even bigger than in HK). Therefore, the PRC would have been disintegrated quickly.

I have a feeling that the 1-party rule of PRC helped them to keep the most historical China in one piece. If PRC were a democracy, it would have been disintegrated by now just like Korea. For instance, HK, Macao, Xinjiang, and Tibet would have been free and independent countries.

Has the 1-party rule of PRC helped them to keep the most historical China in one piece?

Comment: I won't go into if Tibet being a free and independent country would mean the PRC disintegrates. Let me just bring one counter example (of many): India is a democracy (consisting of very diverse states). There is some foreign interference, e.g., by Pakistan. Nevertheless, the country has not disintegrated. Another counter example would be the USA. If your assertion was correct, many countries would disintegrate. You should back up your assertion by some logical arguments.

Comment: It seems these independence movements *seek* democracy, so if the PRC were a fully fledged democracy, perhaps they wouldn't seek independence.

Comment: @Roland, actually, India never had any meaningful foreign interference. A foreign interference to be successful, it should come from at least a Great Power, let alone Superpowers. Even during the cold war, the USA was not hostile to India although India was essentially in the Soviet camp.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones, I doubt. Catalonia is trying to be independent. Quebec tried several times, I guess.

Comment: Definitely. As long as supporting local separatists is a common strategy US strategy - from Yugoslavia to Lybia/Syria. And it would be much more easy for the US to deal with China, if it would be divided.

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by "historical China". The Song Dynasty? The Qin Dynasty during the Warring States period? Maybe the Han dynasty, since most Chinese citizens are Han? During what period?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Collapse of the Soviet Union gave CCP(China Communist Party) a lesson, that "democratization" under US pressure can directly lead to the country desintegration.

So, of course, **YES**, CCP has decisive role in China being keep as a whole, in its historical borders.

Comment: Downvoters, please, leave your comments - answer sounds pretty logical, doesn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115383/discussion-between-user2501323-and-roland).

Answer (score 3):

You can have democracies that respect states leaving, e.g. UK/Scotland, and then you can have democracies not allowing it. E.g. USA (Like the civil war)

Comment: *you can have democracies not allowing it* --- only if u are either a great-power or a super-power.

Comment: I think I can find examples of everything. Pakistan, Yemen, Sudan. UK in regards to Northern Ireland.

Comment: Excuse me, but Yemen democracy is very "significant" when we are talking about countries consistency. UK is a good example, but it is a very old democracy, with old traditions and established political system - which cannot be created in a moment.

Comment: @user366312 At the time of its civil war the US was far from a great power, let alone a super power.

Comment: @mariomario, Yes. But, that is not the point here. The USA didn't receive any [**meaningful**](http://projects.leadr.msu.edu/usforeignrelations/exhibits/show/british-involvement-in-the-ame) external interference.

Comment: I don't think the UK and Scotland is a good example of 'respecting states leaving': Scotland hasn't left yet and we can't really say whether Westminster would accept it happening (yes, they held a referendum. So?). Better examples might be the dissolution of Czechoslovakia or the Handover of Hong Kong?